# Creating (dynamically) a class instance properties from [any] dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion

I have the following situation :

for any given Json I need to apply set of rules.
i.e - masking some specific fields value  ,
replace values of specific fields with some fake data.

I'm getting the "todo" fields list like that:

```
list_of_field_to_change = {"field1": "MASK","Filed2" : "RANDOM(1,10)" ,"field3": "fake.last_name()"}
```

Number of fields --> unlimited
Value of a field contain description of the functionality required to apply on fields values.
So i need to build methods accordingly.
So in example if I get {"field1" : "fake.last_name"}
I need to add method a class to handle this in advance.
pseudo code :

```py
def __init__(self):
    fake = Faker()
    self.field1 = fake.last_name()
def returnJson(self):
    return {'field1 ': self.field1}
```

The big problem - the Json structure is unknown.
it can be deeply nested ,or simple.
in other words - The fields location is unknown.
fields may not exist in the json and it is a valid case,

the only thing is sure - the list of fields im getting.
To solve it ,I think i need to convert this Json to an Object/class,
Once i have an instance which I can bound some methods .
I think this could work but having issue implement this.

```py
import json

json_fileds_to_change = {"field1": "MASK","Filed2" : "RANDOM(1,10)"}


class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_):
        self.__dict__.update(dict_)


#Not sure for how apply the method from give list


def dict2obj(d):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(d), object_hook=obj)
```

Questions:

1.How can i dynamically create a class instance of ANY json?
Not sure the function(copy from other post) above can handle any Json structure?
2.How I can assign methods which should set new values per given fields list?

Comment: Loop through `dict_.entries()` and process the values accordingly. You can use `self.setattr()` to add attributes dynamically.

Comment: thanks @Barmar, Not sure i understand ur suggestion , dict_ has no entires()?

Comment: Sorry, meant `items()`